# updating state -> object -> array -> object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

Getting lost in a deeply nested setState function.

What I am trying to do is to add an object to an array within an object within my components state. I have succeeded in doing so but I am trying to make it so if that object already exists, the function will update the quantity. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**state**

```
this.state = {
    products : [
        {
            productId: 1,
            productImage: 'tee1',
            productName: 'The Road Is Home Tee',
            productPrice: 25
        },
        {
            productId: 2,
            productImage: 'shorts1',
            productName: 'Striped Swim Shorts',
            productPrice: 50
        },
        {
            productId: 3,
            productImage: 'tee2',
            productName: 'Gray Long Sleeve',
            productPrice: 100
        },
        {
            productId: 4,
            productImage: 'hat1',
            productName: 'American Snapback',
            productPrice: 25
        },
        {
            productId: 5,
            productImage: 'shorts2',
            productName: 'American Shorts',
            productPrice: 50
        },
        {
            productId: 6,
            productImage: 'hat2',
            productName: 'Flex Fit Hat',
            productPrice: 100
        }
    ],
    cartData : {
        items: [],
        total: 0
    }
}
```

**addToCart()**

```
addToCart = (productId, size, quantity) => {
    for( let i=0; i < this.state.cartData.items.length; i++ ) {
        if (productId === this.state.cartData.items[i].productData.productId) {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                const items = prevState.cartData.items.map(item => {
                    if(i === (item.productId -1)) {
                        return item.productQuantity + quantity;
                    }
                })

                return {
                    items,
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                cartData: {
                    ...prevState.cartData,
                    items: [...prevState.cartData.items, { productData: this.state.products[productId - 1], productSize: size, productQuantity: quantity }]
                }
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT ***********

NEW CODE IS MORE ORGANIZED AND I HAVE IMPLEMENTED AN IF STATEMENT IN THE BEGINNING THAT CHECKS IF CART IS EMPTY BEFORE I LOOP OVER THE ITEMS. ALSO FIXED A COUPLE SMALL THINGS AND ADDED SOME COMMENTS BUT STILL NOT GETTING THE RESULTS I WOULD LIKE

```
addToCart = (productId, size, quantity) => {
        // IF CART IS EMPTY (CANT USE FOR LOOP)
        if ( this.state.cartData.items.length === 0 ) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                cartData: {
                    ...prevState.cartData,
                    items: [...prevState.cartData.items, { productData: this.state.products[productId - 1], productSize: size, productQuantity: quantity }]
                }
            }))
        }
        // IF CART IS NOT EMPTY
        else {
            // LOOP THROUGH EACH ITEM
            for( let i=0; i < this.state.cartData.items.length; i++ ) {
                // IF PRODUCT EXISTS
                if (productId === this.state.cartData.items[i].productData.productId) {
                    // SET STATE (RETURNS A FUNCTION)
                    this.setState(prevState => {
                        // MAP THROUGH EACH ITEM
                        const items = prevState.cartData.items.map(item => {
                            // IF THE PRODUCT IDS MATCH
                            if(i === (item.productData.productId -1)) {
                                // RETURN AN OBJECT WITH SAME ITEM PROPERTIES
                                // ADJUST QUANTITY
                                return {
                                    ...item,
                                    productQuantity: item.productQuantity + quantity,
                                }
                            }
                            // RETURN UNAFFECTED ITEMS AS WELL
                            else {
                                return item
                            }


                        })

                        // RETURN OUR ITEMS TO SET STATE
                        return {
                            items,
                        }
                    })
                }
                // IF PRODUCT DOES NOT EXIST
                else {
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        cartData: {
                            ...prevState.cartData,
                            items: [...prevState.cartData.items, { productData: this.state.products[productId - 1], productSize: size, productQuantity: quantity }]
                        }
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AS OF NOW MY APPLICATION WILL ADD THE FIRST PRODUCT CORRECTLY. THEN ANYTHING AFTER THAT I START GETTING PROBLEMS. WHEN I TRY TO ADD ANOTHER PRODUCT WITH THE SAME PRODUCT ID IT WILL NOT JUST INCREMENT THE QUANTITY IT CREATES A WHOLE OTHER OBJECT.

sooo lost here please help!!!

p.s.
getting errors that i am not getting with localhost inside of sandbox so not really an option here

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try running the code (will do if you provide a codesandbox or something), but that should help.

```
addToCart = (productId, size, quantity) => {
    for( let i=0; i < this.state.cartData.items.length; i++ ) {
        if (productId === this.state.cartData.items[i].productData.productId) {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                const items = prevState.cartData.items.map(item => {


                    if(i === (item.productId -1)) {
                        // returns a copy of the known item with updated quantity
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            productQuantity: item.productQuantity + quantity,
                        };
                    } else {
                        return item // you need to return items that are not modified too
                    }


                })

                return {
                    items,
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                cartData: {
                    ...prevState.cartData,
                    items: [...prevState.cartData.items, { productData: this.state.products[productId - 1], productSize: size, productQuantity: quantity }]
                }
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me, but I just tried it and having the same issue as before. When I console.log() my cartData it's empty...

Answer (score 0):

It works. I hope it helps you. (some changes for a more organized code):

```
const products = [
{
  productId: 1,
  productImage: 'tee1',
  productName: 'The Road Is Home Tee',
  productPrice: 25
},
{
  productId: 2,
  productImage: 'shorts1',
  productName: 'Striped Swim Shorts',
  productPrice: 50
},
{
  productId: 3,
  productImage: 'tee2',
  productName: 'Gray Long Sleeve',
  productPrice: 100
},
{
  productId: 4,
  productImage: 'hat1',
  productName: 'American Snapback',
  productPrice: 25
},
{
  productId: 5,
  productImage: 'shorts2',
  productName: 'American Shorts',
  productPrice: 50
},
{
  productId: 6,
  productImage: 'hat2',
  productName: 'Flex Fit Hat',
  productPrice: 100
}
```

]

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({
items: [],
total: 0
})

const isProductExist= productId =>
  cart.items.find(product => product.productId == productId)

addToCart = (productId, size, quantity) => {
  if (isProductExist(productId)) {
  setCart(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    items: cart.items.map(item => {
      if (item.productId == productId) item.productQuantity += quantity
      item.productQuantity
      return item
    })
  }))
} else {
  setCart(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    items: [
      ...prevState.items,
      {
        productId: products[productId - 1].productId,
        productSize: size,
        productQuantity: quantity
      }
    ]
  }))
 }
}
```

Comment: very confused about this. for starters, why make these class functions a const? I'm getting a ton of errors trying this answer. i appreciate the help just not really sure how to implement this.

Comment: About const you're right, updated. Can you share the errors? I can't guess.

Comment: Cool. So I got rid of useState since I already have a state in my application. Also, turned const isProductExist into an arrow function. Then, changed setCart() to this.setState(). Next I put the return item outside of the if statement since .map was expecting the return not the if statement. Then just fixed a couple small reference errors like cart should have been this.state.cartData. And after that I'm not getting any errors.

When I run the code now, each item is still being pushed to my list even if it already exists. I'm wondering if isProductExist is working correctly?

Comment: Got it @Esther-I - was just a matter of targeting the right property. product.productData.productId rather than product.productId! Weird it never gave me a reference error.